# Jump to any word like Easymotion in Vim?

Tags: xvim

I install Xvim in my Xcode. However, if I want to jump to some word on the screen, I have to jump to that line first then press several "w" to get to it. Or use '/' to find that word then press several "n".

It's quite annoying! Is there a better way to handle this situation?